# getting the scroll value from a WebBrowser Control C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, scrollbar

I am trying to get the Y scroll index for a web page in the WebBrowser control but I can't access the values for the built in Scroll bar.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For IE in standards mode (with a doctype, as you say) `scrollTop` is a property of the `<html>` element, not the `<body>`:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
int scrollTop = htmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].ScrollTop;
```

(A nicer way to get to the `<html>` element would be good, if anyone knows of one.)

Comment: HtmlDocument doesnt have a documentElement property according to VS :S are you using a different library?

Comment: I'm using COM via C++, and accessing documentElement via IHTMLDocument3.  Not much use in C#!  8-)  I've changed my answer to give tested C# code - sorry about that, I should have tested it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to target an HTML element to bring it into view? If that is what you are after you can do this...

htmlDoc.GetElementById("tag_id_string_goes_here").ScrollIntoView(true);

true aligns it with the top and false with the bottom of the element. You can also use ScrollRectangle to get the dimensions of the scrollable region.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollTop;
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
```