# How to access the scrollbar of a webbrowser control in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, scrollbar

My webbrowser control has to be disabled (enabled = false) so that the user can't click in it.
This also disables the access to the scrollbar so I'm thinking about creating another scrollbar next to the control that gets and passes its values from and to the webbrowser's scrollbar.
For that, I need to access the webbrowser scrollbar control. How can I find it ?
webbrowser.Controls.Count returns zero.

Comment: ...or is there perhaps a way to disable the webbrowser view without disabling its scrollbar ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I don't know if there is any method to acccess the scrollbar position programmaticly. You can however, [scroll by element name:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollintoview.aspx)

```
        private void ScrollToElement(String elemName)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElementCollection elems = doc.All.GetElementsByName(elemName);
            if (elems != null && elems.Count > 0) 
            {
                HtmlElement elem = elems[0];

                elem.ScrollIntoView(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785792/getting-the-scroll-value-from-a-webbrowser-control-c) question for other possibilities.

EDIT:

See question [Scrolling WebBrowser programatically sometimes doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975764/scrolling-webbrowser-programatically-sometimes-doesnt-work/1002308#1002308)